# How to delete data from database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to make a form where sellers can insert new items, new category and delete items. Now I have problem with DELETE. 
This is my code and if somebody know how to fix it please help.

```
String id = "42";

    try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projekat","root","");

            PreparedStatement prepared_statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM artikli WHERE id= ? ;");
            prepared_statement.setString(1, id);
            int result_set = prepared_statement.executeUpdate();
            if (result_set > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Can't delete");
            }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Explain what the problem is instead of just saying that there is a problem.

Comment: I don't know, always I get a else result. Can't Delete. And in mySql database item is still there.

Comment: Ok sorry everybody I forget to explain what is a problem. I always get a else result. So items are still in mySql database.
This is result "response.sendRedirect("Prodaja2.jsp?error=Can'tDelete");"

Comment: Check with a debugger, or by logging, what the variable `id` really contains when this code is called. Then check if there really is a record in the table `artikli` with that value in the `id` column.

Comment: And remove that superfluous semi-colon at the end of the query. You should also learn to ALWAYS close connections, in a finally block, or using the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: prepared_statement.setString(1, id); instead of this just try to put a value of type integer and see how it goes I'm not sure what your first line of code produces, instead of id type 1,2,3... and see if the the first if executes

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been required since 2007.

Comment: @esner_togo Ok, when I put id number from my database 1,2,3 it works. So that's mean my variable "id" is not good? Thanks for help people.

Comment: @EJP So is Class.forName necessary to put in my code? Or my project can works without that line?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @esner_togo Still no because i don't know what to do with id variable. I want when somebody press delete on some product to delete that item automatically, and I cant fix it. Only what i can do is to check id in database or table and enter the id number of that item. But I am beginner, and i just want to practice so i am researching now what else can I do.

Comment: When somebody presses delete on some product you should have an event fire up! Then, on the event section, assign an index to a variable (similar like you did above with the id=42, your id should always change depending on the item that is clicked of course ). So string id should be a dynamic type of value which changes, instead of "42" try to use a parameter of the event to specify the change.

Comment: Cf comment given by @eugensunic, if the id is a numerical type in the database (eg INT) pass the parameter as an Int: `prepared_statement.setInt(1,id)`. The type of `id` should be `int` or `Integer` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");

        try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projekat","root","");
                PreparedStatement prepared_statement = null;

                String strQuery = "DELETE FROM artikli WHERE id= ?";
                prepared_statement = connection.prepareStatement(strQuery);
                prepared_statement.setString(1, id);
                int result_set = prepared_statement.executeUpdate();

                if (result_set > 0)
                {
                    // System.out.println(result_set);                    
                    response.sendRedirect("Prodaja2.jsp");
                }
                else
                {
                    // System.out.println(result_set);
                    response.sendRedirect("Prodaja2.jsp?error=Can'tDelete");
                }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        out.print(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            stmtProd.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

In your code the semicolon after the query may be conflicting. And also don't forget to close the connections in the finally block created because it may lead to resource leak and connection will remain active even if the user logs out.

Comment: Try this ***why?*** Mere code isn't an answer. You have to *explain,* and often the explanation is sufficient without any code at all.

Comment: @EJP...I already added explanation at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One error is here, that is in your syntax

Change the code

```
 PreparedStatement prepared_statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM artikli WHERE id= ? ;");
```

to

```
 PreparedStatement prepared_statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM artikli WHERE id= ?");
```

If there is no other errors, Check value in id, there is a chance of null value.

Comment: I tried that before, that is not solution. But thanks for try to help.